# Getting OAuth settings from env var with full stop in key

Tags: docker, servicestack

I am using docker linux container to run my servicestack application and I need to be able to read the OAuth keys from environment variables defined in my docker-compose.yml.

It appears impossible to do this due to the full stop in the variable name.

For example in OAuthProvider.cs (https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Auth/OAuthProvider.cs) line 26:

```
this.ConsumerKey = appSettings.GetString($"oauth.{oAuthProvider}.{consumerKeyName}");
```

It is reading for example the key `oauth.google.ConsumerKey`.

Linux doesn't support full stops in environment variables.  Using the debugger I can see that if I put the variables in like:

```
environment:
  - oauth.RedirectUrl=http://example.com
  - oauth.CallbackUrl=http://example.com/auth/{0}
  - oauth.basecamp.ConsumerKey=fgshghfdhfghgfdhf
  - oauth.basecamp.ConsumerSecret=fdghfdghdfghgdfhdfghfgd
```

Then they are removed.  I did some research and this is common issue, if the env var has a full stop then it gets removed.  I cannot find any workaround for this.

Do you have any idea how I can pass these hard coded settings with docker environment variable?

Here is representation of my entire dockerfile for reference:

```
ARG BUILD_MODE=Release
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install openssh-server unzip -y 
RUN curl -sSL https://aka.ms/getvsdbgsh | /bin/sh /dev/stdin -v latest -l ~/vsdbg
COPY sshd_config /etc/ssh/
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Project/Project.csproj", "Project/"]
COPY ["Project.ServiceModel/Project.ServiceModel.csproj", "Project.ServiceModel/"]
COPY ["Project.ServiceInterface/Project.ServiceInterface.csproj", "Project.ServiceInterface/"]
COPY ["NuGet.config", "NuGet.config"]
RUN dotnet restore "Project/Project.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Project"
RUN dotnet build "Project.csproj" -c "$BUILD_MODE" -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Project.csproj" -c "$BUILD_MODE" -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT service ssh start && echo "root:$SSH_PASSWORD" | chpasswd && dotnet Project.dll
```

And this is docker-compose:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  project:
    build:
      context: E:\project\
      dockerfile: E:\project\project\Dockerfile
    image: project:local
    ports:
      - "57008:80"
      - "57009:443"
      - "57001:2222"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - "db"
    environment:
      - oauth.RedirectUrl=http://example.com
      - oauth.CallbackUrl=http://example.com/auth/{0}
      - oauth.basecamp.ConsumerKey=fgshghfdhfghgfdhf
      - oauth.basecamp.ConsumerSecret=fdghfdghdfghgdfhdfghfgd
  db:
    image: postgres:10.9
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: fdgdfgdfgdf
      POSTGRES_USER: project
    ports:
      - "5445:5432"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide your own custom [AppSettings provider](https://docs.servicestack.net/appsettings) or use the `DictionarySettings` and populate it with a mapped environment variable that's suitable to use in Docker, e.g:

Use underscore separators in Docker:

```
environment:
  - oauth_RedirectUrl=http://example.com
  - oauth_CallbackUrl=http://example.com/auth/{0}
  - oauth_basecamp_ConsumerKey=fgshghfdhfghgfdhf
  - oauth_basecamp_ConsumerSecret=fdghfdghdfghgdfhdfghfgd
```

Then create a new Dictionary AppSettings using the keys ServiceStack expects, e.g:

```
string env(string key) => 
    Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(key.Replace(".","_"));

var envSettings = new DictionarySettings(new Dictionary<string,string> {
    ["oauth.RedirectUrl"] = env("oauth.RedirectUrl"),
    ["oauth.CallbackUrl"] = env("oauth.CallbackUrl"),
    ["oauth.basecamp.ConsumerKey"] = env("oauth.basecamp.ConsumerKey"),
    ["oauth.basecamp.ConsumerSecret"] = env("oauth.basecamp.ConsumerSecret"),
});
```

Then use that in your Auth Providers, e.g:

```
new MyAuthProvider(envSettings)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I added explicit mapping and now it works.